# Coloring density plot in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram, density-plot

When I use following code to generate a density plot:

```
require(ggplot2)
set.seed(seed=10)
n <- 10000
s.data <- data.frame(score = rnorm(n,500,100),
                     gender = sample(c("Male","Female","No Response"),size=n,replace=T,prob=c(.4,.55,.05)),
                     major = sample(c("A","B","C","D"),size=n,replace=T,prob=c(.02,.25,.05,.68))) 
ggplot(s.data, aes(major,..density..,fill=major,group=1)) + 
  geom_histogram() + facet_wrap(~ gender)
```

[image]

I cannot distinguish between categories of "major" by color.

What I want to get is density plot similar to this frequency plot in the sense of colors and legend:

```
ggplot(s.data, aes(major,fill=major)) + 
    geom_histogram() + facet_wrap(~ gender)
```

[image]

This question is following my question ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16377679/density-plot-in-ggplot)) which is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16373738/not-understanding-the-behavior-of-density).

Comment: [This SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11773822/fill-colors-in-geom-histogram-density-group-1) question could help

Comment: I think "density" is reserved for continuous variables.

Comment: @DidzisElferts Thanks for comment. I used `ggplot(s.data, aes(x=major, fill = major)) + geom_histogram(aes(y=..count../sum(..count..))) + facet_wrap(~ gender)`  But it did not give what I wanted. It just changed the scale of frequency plot.

Comment: What if you just pre-calculate everything yourself and just plot the result?

Answer (score 1):

You can still try frequency plot with facet parameter `scale="free_y"`:

```
ggplot(s.data, aes(major,..count..,fill=major)) + 
  geom_histogram() + facet_wrap(~ gender, scale="free_y")
```

[image]

Comment: Even though it is not direct answer of the question, it solved my problem beautifully. Thank you very much @topchef for showing "scale="free_y""